# How to get BaseDN of Directory Server from IP or serverName

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, openldap

I am working on LDAP, I have installed OpenLDAP on my local machine and created a RootDSE as dc=wave,dc=com.

and I am trying to fetch this baseDN using this code:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}", server), "CN=Manager,dc=wave,dc=com", "secret");
string dnPath;
try
{
    dnPath = directoryEntry.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
}
catch
{
    dnPath = "";
}
```

but it always fall in exception, also why do I need to pass whole dn for username?

same thing if I try with Active Directory server it works perfectly, also I don't need to pass the whole dn for username.

any Idea?

Comment: Duplicate of own post [How to get distinguishname for OpenLDAP sever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122947/how-to-get-distinguishname-for-openldap-sever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System.DirectoryServices namespace really only works with Active Directory.  You should switch over to using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols when working with any other directory.  You'll probably find that its even better when working with AD as well.

Comment: Thanks Sam!, is there any good example I can refer to. this how I am trying to connect to OpenLDAP, but it always give an error using (LdapConnection ldap = new LdapConnection("localhost:389"))
        {
            //ldap.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
            ldap.Bind(new NetworkCredential("cn=manager,dc=wave,dc=com", "secret"));
        }